# Whats does ''being embarrassed around someone'' mean?

Tags: meaning

Like for example: ''I am embarrassed whenever I am around him''

Comment: What part is confusing you?  What *embarrassed* means? or what it means to be around someone?

Comment: @Jim just all together

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is expressing discomfort with being physically nearby to the person in question. This feeling of shame or awkwardness could be due to a number of factors, especially if there is history between the two people.

Comment: I also mean ''being embarrassed with someone'' is ''around'' and ''with'' the same?

Comment: Yes, either can work in American english, although "around" would be used more often in casual speech.

Comment: what about embarrassed did you mean mainly ill at ease and shy in this case?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 0):

The use of *around* here is not standard English, something I am glad to say have never encountered, and certainly something I as a native speaker of the older generation would never use and would discourage others from using.

However, it is evident that *around someone* here means:

> “in his presence”

O tempora, O mores!

Comment: In my experience (AmE, mid-50’s) this use is very common.  It would never even occur to me that some might consider it non-standard.

Comment: @Jim — As you say AmE. I speak the BrE variety. Any non-native learning English in a formal environment is unlikely to encounter it.